# Remove special character at the beginning of words in Unix

Tags: regex, bash, text-processing

I need help removing special characters from the beginning of the word in a Unix shell.

For example I have the list of words like this,

```
'aaa
'bbb
'ccc
'ddd
```

I want to remove the quotes and get output like this,

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

How can I remove only the quote at the beginning of each word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to match at a **word boundary**, which is delimited with `\b`.

So for example, if you were using sed and wanted to remove a single quote `'` at the beginning of any word, you would use

```
sed "s/'\b//g"
```

Which means "replace any single quote immediately before a word boundary with an empty string".

Additionally, if you aren't worried about at the beginning of the line, you can use the specifier `^`, which matches the start of a line.

```
sed "s/^'//g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to:

```
echo 'aaa 'bbb 'ccc 'ddd | tr -d "'"
```

Comment: this may do something else than OP asked. I feel the other answer is better, the `\b` one.

Comment: This will only work if the quotes only appear at the beginning of words. Otherwise, If you have something like `'I don't have one` will become `I dont have one` instead of `I don't have one`